# WordPress site crashes after changing some general settings in wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Received a WorpPress site from a client to implement register and login functions. Site works fine but when i change any of two specific setting the site crashes. Specifically the Settings -> Site Language or the Settings -> Anyone can register. After changin the options to initial values all remains the same. The theme crashes and fallsback to some blank one. The site becomes just a blank page with only a some text from the header and the footer. Any ideias why this is happening?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found what was the problem. It was because of one of the plugins. I deactivated all the plugins, activeated the Anyone can register option then reactivated all the lugins. All works now.